# Caching notification usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, webforms

I'm working on an ASP.NET WebForms project. I created a notification usercontrol (`ucNotifications.ascx)`. This usercontrol is placed inside a masterpage. The notifications don't change very frequently, so I'd like to cache that usercontrol for some minutes, altough, the cached information is sensitive; the information varies by the userid `Session["userid"]. One user can't see other's notifications.

I [read on internet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms550239(v%3Doffice.14)) that I should use the`VaryByCustom` attribute in my `OutputCache` tag, and also implement a custom handle in my Global.asax, but I didn't quite understand that code.

How can I do that and is it a bad idea if so?

Answer (score 0):

After some additional searching, I was able to solve the problem with that:

**ucNotifications.ascx**

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="300" VaryByCustom="userid" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

**Global.asax**

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
      if (custom == "userid")
      {
         if (context.Session["userid"] != null)
              return context.Session["userid"].ToString();

          return string.Empty;
       }
       return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```